# how to create htaccess for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

i have subdomain.domain.com in domain.com, when i type subdomain.domain.com in browser, and the URL written http://subdomain.domain.com/%20//subdomain.domain.com and i have .htaccess like this:

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.jubelmart.com/index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

can i get help for this?

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`i would try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /%20//subdomain.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%20//subdomain.domain.com/index.php/$1 [L]
```

sure `/20%//` uri segment is correct? i really don't think using double slashes is a good practice `//`